# sudo vim not working MacOSX(10.11.6)

Tags: ruby, macos, vim, sudo

On running `sudo vim` I'm getting the following error-

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/ruby/lib/libruby.2.3.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/vim
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

running below commands as `root` user-

`which -a vim` returns the following-

```
/usr/local/bin/vim
/usr/bin/vim
```

I also have MacVim installed.

`which -a ruby` returns-

```
/usr/local/bin/ruby
/usr/bin/ruby
```

`ruby -v` returns-

```
ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x86_64-darwin15]
```

I don't want to create alias for vim in the root. I'm looking to fix the existing installation in `/usr/local/bin/vim`

Comment: Runnng `which -a vim` and `which -a ruby` tells you the answer for **your** userid, but `sudo vim` runs `vim` as **root** not you.

Comment: I don't get it. It's a valid problem, I didn't find any resolution online, and it's defined clearly. Why the negative points?

Comment: It's not clear at all to me why starting vim evokes a Ruby error, but since both Ruby and vim are programmer tools, and questions about programmer tools are on-topic here, I think this question is not off-topic for reason of being about "general computing hardware and software."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI this was already asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1096438/brew-upgrade-broke-vim-on-os-x-dyld-library-not-loaded/1096439), but that solution didn't work for me, so just in case, here's how I fixed it:

`/usr/bin/vim` is your system vim, but you've chosen to override it with `/usr/local/bin/vim` (probably from homebrew, right?). I'm willing to bet that running system vim will actually work and not throw up that error, but obviously you want to use the other version.

I think it's just some issue with brew's vim linking to the wrong local version of ruby or some other black magic, so the easiest fix (for me at least), was literally just restarting from scratch! `brew uninstall vim && brew install vim` if you used Homebrew, or the equivalent if you did something else.

Note: obviously if you require a specific build of vim you'll need to include the version number.